# How to derive formula for $\sin(A-B)$ from formula for $\sin(A+B)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It has been a while since I have done any maths and am struggling with this question -

> Using the addition law $$\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B) + \cos(A)\sin(B)$$ and the fact that $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$, show that
>   $$\sin(A-B) = \sin(A)\cos(B) - \cos(A)\sin(B)$$

I am really confused as to where to even start, so any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Hint: Substitute $-B$ into your expression for sin(A+B) and use the identities.

Comment: Let $C=-B$. Then $\sin(A-B)=\sin(A+C)$. See if you can take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\quad A-B=A+(-B)\quad $$

Answer (score 1):

There's hardly anything to do:
\begin{align}
\sin(A-B) & = \sin(A+(-B)) = \sin A\cos(-B) + \cos A \sin(-B) \\[6pt]
& = \sin A\cos B + (\cos A)(-\sin B)
\end{align}
followed by one trivial step.